# how to install ubuntu on new hard disk with boot partition?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, bootloader

I want to install 3 kind of Linux distribution on my disk. 
The first will be ubuntu.

I want that the grub will be defile by the ubuntu - and when i installing the other distribution the ubuntu grub will not overwrite.

So i rad about that in the installation and the partition setup i can create the first partition that will be 'boot' and to load the grub there.

1. is it possible ?
2. how to do it ?
3. what the side of this boot partition ?
4. when i continue the installation ( set 15 GB to SWAP and 100 GB to ubuntu ) the installation tell me something about "Reserved bios boot area" - i don't see anything about it and don't understand is i need it or not

Comment: No need for /boot partition. If new UEFI system you will need the ESP - efi system partition for booting, but that is different than /boot. You also cannot share a /boot between installs. Better just to know how to reinstall grub for Ubuntu either by booting into it from other install, and/or using Ubuntu live installer. I have 4 or 5 Ubuntu installs on my system(s). I keep entire system in 25GB including /home. But then have a large /mnt/data partition for all data which I mount in each install. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2315714

Comment: sorry, i still don't understand :( how to keep the grub to not overwrite on the other linux installation

Comment: Is this an UEFI system with gpt partitioning. With gpt, you can install in UEFI boot mode but must have the ESP - efi system partition (FAT32 with boot flag). Or if booting in BIOS boot mode from gpt partitioned drive you must have the bios_grub partition (1 or 2MB unformatted with bios_grub flag). But all systems really need to be installed in same boot mode, either all UEFI or all BIOS. What is your System. Post current partitions above to preserve formatting: `sudo parted -l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install GRUB on the MBR (Master Boot Record) without a /boot partition.  Grub will then function as the Boot Loader for all your operating systems, and can detect them on startup.  For more info see this guide:

[Setting Up Multi-Boot with GRUB](https://superuser.com/questions/178492/setting-up-a-multi-boot-system-with-grub)

Then, as you add new installs, just update the boot record files manually and make sure your new install doesn't overwrite your consolidated GRUB configs.